# How to make a dynamic menu in base template using django

Tags: django, django-templates, renderpartial

I'm about to start a new project and I think this time django is the way to go. I've been reading the documentation for the past two weeks and it looks promissing.

Ok, the thing is that I could not find anything about (in C# MVC called) Partial Rendering. For example if I want a dynamic menu where the menu-items comes from the database, then I would expect that the base template (or master page) renders the menu on each request (the partial renderer invokes another action or renders a template with some session data). So, the menu comes for free as long as my template inherits from this base template.

Honestly, I have no clue on how to achieve this.

---

What I would like is some code in the base template that uses data that is not contained in the child template. I don't want to include an extra variable (maybe 'menu_list_items') every time I call render_to_response('child_content.html',context). Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could either use a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#template-context-processors), or a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/) to provide this functionality.

A context_processor is a simple function which can add objects to every RequestContext. A custom template tag can have its own template snippet and context which could render the menu for you.

Answer (score 0):

For the template reusing: you should just create a base template for the generic layout, and use detailed templates for the individual pages. This is already covered in detail by the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/templates/).

What I tend to do for those generic parts (say for example, a menu highlighting the current part of the site the use is on), is to create my own `render_to_response` functions, akin to the following:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response as django_render_to_response
def render_to_response(template, params, context_instance):
    return django_render_to_response(template,
                        AppendStandardParams(request, params),
                        context_instance)
```

The `ApplyStandardParams` method then configures the menu based on the current path:

```
def AppendStandardParams(request, params):
    if request.META['PATH_INFO'].startswith('/customer'):
        params['category'] = 'customer'
        params['title'] = 'Customer overview'
    # and so on for all different parts
```

These `category` and `title` tags in this example are some values used to highlight the menu, configure titles, and so on. For example:

```
<!-- Customer menu entry: change class if this is the current category. -->
<li{% if category == "customer" %} class="selected"{% endif %}>Customers</li>
```

Finally, to use it in a view, instead of the normal `render_to_response` import, I just do something like `from lib.views import *`, which makes my custom version available in the view. This way the syntax of all code in the views stays the same, but I don't have to customize the menu every time I create a new view or app.